# Who invented the independence notation $\perp \!\!\! \perp$?

Tags: probability, notation, history

This is more of a historical question: who invented the notation $\perp \!\!\! \perp$ for denoting (conditional) independence?

Comment: To whom it may concern, this question seems to be on-topic. We have many questions on (history of) notation in probability & statistics, and a tag for them [tag:notation].

Comment: So the tiny orthogonal vectors ⊥ mean marginal independence and with two vertical lines it's conditional independence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have often seen it associated with AP Dawid 1979, "Conditional Independence in Statistical Theory." For example page 373 of [these notes](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis520/papers/Bishop_8.2.pdf). I have no idea if Dawid actually invented it or popularized it.

Update 8/17/19: According to Wikipedia, the symbol was introduced by Elfving: "Elfving introduced the statistical symbol for probabilistic independence ⊥⊥, which is a stronger condition than orthogonality ⊥, by the 1950s."

Comment: In the 'handbook of graphical models' by Maathuis ea it is written explicitly by Milan Studeny "The author of this chapter was told that the conditional independence symbol $\perp \!\!\! \perp $ was proposed by Dawid and Mouchart in their discussion in the late 1970s"